# EXE4J_JAVA_HOME error

Tags: java, java-8, exe4j

Note: Do not put this as duplicate because nobody has posted this error related with java 8.

I have exe4j for a while now. Everything was running fine.
But when I installed Java 8, It started gaving an error EXE4J_JAVA_HOME.

Here is a screen:

[image]

Note that  I have Java 1.8.0_05. for 64bits.

How do I fix that??

-->This is important and I need to get this fixed quickly.

Comment: Well... First of all: Where **does** your `EXE4J_JAVA_HOME` point to?

Comment: @skiwi When I had exe4j with java 7, I didn't need to point anything.
Now I pointed it to C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe but still nothing

Comment: check java `classpath`

Comment: the name `…JAVA_HOME` suggests that it should point to the `jre` directory rather than the `bin\java.exe` within it. You can try to set `EXE4J_LOG` to `yes` to get a log file in your `%TMP%` directory which might tell you why the automated lookup failed.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly same error message, when trying to run Java based program on Windows.

I had Java 7 already installed, but **this** case appears that program requires Java 8 version.

Next very important thing is the version of the program. If program is 32-bit, it requires Java 8 32-bit version to be installed.
If program is 64-bit, it will requires corresponding 64-bit Java version.

In my case, I needed to install Java 8 32-bit version and program runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for it, in my case I am using `OpenJDK 8`

So I had to set **Env Variable for my Account** (if you dont have Admin access) with following variable & value

```
DBVIS_JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\username\Documents\JDK8\jre
```

Read more about it [here](https://support.dbvis.com/support/solutions/articles/1000231944-how-do-i-change-the-java-version-that-dbvisualizer-use-)

Answer (score -3):

You should install both Java 7 32-bit and Java 7 64-bit.

Comment: This definitely won't help